# Sync Local database windows phone with database server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, windows-phone-7, synchronization, local-database

How to sync local database of windows phone with database on the server, for this case, rails server using sqlite ... Any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to manually implement the synchronization layer. There are currently no built-in tools to do that. Consider building a web-service that is able to accept incoming data push/pull requests and act on the database accordingly.